# mongodb global authentication

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have set up a global admin with many roles such as `clusterAdmin`, any DB admin etc. However, I can only authenticate when inside the `admin` database.

For that reason, `mongo -u admin -p` does not work. I get `auth fails` error. However, when I just launch the `mongo` shell and then switch to the `admin` db and authenticate, it works.

```
mongo
> use admin
> db.auth('admin', <my password>)
```

What I want to do is

```
mongo
> db.auth('admin', <my password>)
```

How can I authenticate without having to use the `admin` db? Is there such a thing? I followed the mongodb documentation, read several guides and I can't seem to get this to work.

I want to use the `mongodump` to backup all databases, but it won't work because it cannot authenticate.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured it out.. Using `--authenticationDatabase admin` works.

Comment: is that in mongotop. where does that go for normal operation, in /etc/mongod.cfg or ??

Comment: That's when you do the operation, e.g. `mongo --authenticationDatabase admin ...`